# How to show that inverse of a continuous function is continuous

Tags: general-topology

Let $\tau_u$ denote the usual topology on $\mathbb R$. Given that $f:(\mathbb R,\tau_u)\to (\mathbb R,\tau_u)$ is one-one, onto and continuous. I want to show that $f^{-1}$ is also continuous. It is enough to show that $f$ is open.

Let $G$ be open in $\mathbb R$. Let $f(a)\in f(G)$. Since, $G$ is open, $\exists \delta>0$ such that $B_\delta(a)\subset G$. This gives $f(B_\delta(a))\subset f(G)$. Now how to use the continuity of $f$ to find a ball contained in $f(G)$? Am I out of track? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Show that if $f$ is one-to-one, onto, and continuous, then it must be strictly monotonic, either increasing or decreasing.

Comment: @B.M. Scott: A little detailed hint would be more helpful. Thanks!